# Zoom issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm looking into an issue where not only is the zoom feature disabled on IE but the page seems to load in at 200%. It's nothing to do with the browser itself, it's the build that's causing the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: It only seems to affect IE10 and IE11

Comment: Which build do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue was due to this viewport being added to the body of the sass/css:

@-ms-viewport{width:1100px}

Once removed the problem was solved on all version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing ctrl - keys to zoom out the page.

Comment: That's also the issue as that doesn't work either, only on this page mind, works fine on other pages which concludes it must be the coding.

Comment: Whats the version of your IE? Have you tried to update to the latest version?

Comment: Try following these steps: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/86756-internet-explorer-zoom-enable-disable.html

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen in other browser's as well?

if so i think you have an attribute in a css file called zoom that has been set. 
try and remove it.

Comment: No this is just IE, works fine in all other browsers, very strange. Have tried adding zoom:1 with no joy.